# Is this string properly installed?

Tags: string-instruments, bridge

A friend of mine lend me his 5-strings bass for me to practice for a fill-in.

The instrument feels absolutely flaweless, and the sound is perfect. However when taking a close look at the bridge, I noticed the low B string was slightly higher than the other strings. It even seems it is going to pop out from the bridge at any given time (although it doesn't feel like it, and I have been playing it all day long without any troubles).

When lowering the B string tension, I cannot push the ring any deeper, which worries me a lot. I'm just hoping it will not pop out during the gig ..

Is this a normal state ? Should I get a thinner B string for it to fit deeper in the bridge ?

EDIT : This is a Warwick Streamer LX 5

[image]

Comment: If it hasn't popped out yet, it's unlikely to do so.  If I owned this axe, I would file the anchor points open so the string could fit thru -- looks like it's the string diameter, not the end loop, which is the problem.

Comment: Okay, if it is unlikely to pop out, I'll just leave it as-is. I did not quite understand your tip though. What do you mean "to file the anchor points open" ? The narrow space through which the string goes is not adjustable, it looks like a fixed space

Comment: That's why you'd need to file it open!   If it was adjustable, you could adjust it.  But don't do that.  Particularly as it isn't your instrument.

Comment: Have you ever taken a shop class dude?

Comment: @Tama, if you are addressing to me, no I haven't.

Comment: When saying I did not understand the tip, I meant i **really** did not understand the meaning of "to file sthg open"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd prefer to just comment on your question, but I still don't have enough rep...

As others commented, it seems the string is stable in that position. But it really seems to be incorrectly installed - it seems the ring was supposed to be horizontally aligned with the bridge, instead of vertically as it looks in your picture. Take a look at this picture: [image: Warwick Streamer LX]

You could try to play a little more vigorously just to see if the extra tension will pop it out. If it doesn't, you'll be a little more comfortable to play without having to worry with it; if it does, you'll need to install it again and you can align the ring, but at least it happened out of stage and you'll have time to do it calmly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip ! What I have done is loose the string down, then using a plier to softly press the end of the string, to make it slimmer. Then it could fit deeper in the bridge, and it seems to be fine. I could not afford taking the risk of seeing it pop out during the performance (especially if it hits my face or something really bad like this ..)